# Google sheets ImportHTML table data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so im trying to import data from openinsider.com this site provides information about insiders buying and selling stock in a company etc.

to pull the data need im using this =IMPORTHTML(A3,"table",12)

the html is in A3 - http://openinsider.com/search?q=GM

what i would like is for 'GM' to be easily changed to another ticker such as 'MSFT' by typing it into cell B1 is this possibe?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `&` operator will do:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://openinsider.com/search?q="&B1,"table")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, glad you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use concatenation

```
=CONCAT("http://openinsider.com/search?q=",B1)
```